# Material Style In Qml Does Not Load Colors

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

i used methods [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qtquickcontrols2-styles.html) to use material design in my QtQuick project and used Accent and Themes from [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qtquickcontrols2-material.html) controls loading in material style correctly in normal qml files , but in qml files loaded by loader result is like this:

[image: image of button]
this loader is in main.qml :

```
Loader{
    id:myLoader
    anchors.fill: parent
    source: "LoginPage.qml"
}
```

and here is my dynamic qml file

```
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.3
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0
Rectangle{
    Material.theme: Material.Dark
    Material.accent: Material.Teal
    property string error_msg: ""
    id: loginPage
    Button {
        id: button
        width: 80
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 0
        font.family: "B Nazanin"
        enabled: webView.loadProgress == 100 ? true:false
        KeyNavigation.tab: button1
        Material.accent: Material.Orange

        onClicked: {
            login()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Got any code to show us?

Comment: @dtech updated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dark there is presumed to have a dark background. It will not set your window background for you, it only affects GUI controls. And the button in particular doesn't use use the accent color, just the foreground color, unless toggle is enabled, in which case it will use the accent color to signify that.

```
  Material.theme: Material.Dark
  Material.accent: Material.Teal


  Rectangle {
    anchors.fill: r2
    color: "#262626"
  }

  Row {
    id: r1
    Button {
      text: "test"
      checkable: true
      Material.accent: Material.Orange
    }
    Button {
      text: "test"
      checkable: true
    }
  }

  Rectangle {
    anchors.fill: r2
  }

  Row {
    id: r2
    anchors.top: r1.bottom
    Button {
      text: "test"
      checkable: true
      Material.accent: Material.Orange
    }
    Button {
      text: "test"
      checkable: true
    }
  }
```

[image]

As you see, on a white background, the dark theme button looks blurry and washed out. If you want to set the button color, that would be the `Material.background` whereas the text would be `Material.foreground`.

Comment: ``Material.background`` and ``Material.foreground`` solved everything, i dont use white background , i used a ``LinearGradient``

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
Just use **ApplicationWindow** as your root element and it will work.

And additionally you have to load Material before instantiating QML.

```
QGuiApplication application(argc, argv);
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
QQuickStyle::setStyle("Material");
```